# How to send notifications based on location?

Tags: notifications

I  have multiple places I visit Home , Office , Church and 2nd office.

Every time I reach any of those,  I  need to call my parents. I am trying to have a notification sent as soon as I reach any of those locations

Comment: You could use one of the plenty [Location Alerts & Reminders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert) (disclosure: link goes to my Android site).

Answer (score 0):

There are many many apps on the Google Play Store that do this.

If you want to stick to a basic and free app, you can use [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep).

Simply create notes for each event and add the location to the note, Google will then remind you.

Here is a tutorial, [on an external site](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-create-location-based-reminders-in-google-keep/).